# Light fixture with 2 hot wires, with switch off

Tags: electrical

The light fixture had a fan on it, was fairly new, but above dinning table so removed it, the box has 3 lines with 2 being hot, even with switch off. Puzzled, the fan worked when I took it down but I left it a while and forgot how it was wired when i returned to it, any help would be great.[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo showing the back of the box for the switch that controlls this fan/light?

Comment: Two switches, one for fan and one for light?  Any other lights, outlets not working?

Comment: Were some of these wires only connected to each other, not to the fan?  Which ones?